# Combining continuous and binary data in unsupervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, pca, unsupervised-learning, feature-engineering

I am working on cluster detection applied to housing data. Each data point has some continuous features, such as house size, and some discrete ones, such as the number of garages (0 or 1).

At the moment I scale each feature to the unit interval, then run PCA, and feed the PCA components to a clustering algorithm (HDBSCAN).

What I'm worried about is that all the binary features will then be represented at the extremes of the unit interval. In other words, the garage feature difference between houses with and without garages (both fairly common) will be as extreme as the size feature difference between the single smallest and single largest houses in the data set.

If this were supervised learning, I'd expect the learning algorithm to compensate for any problems caused by this by assigning a lower weight to the binary feature if this is a problem. As I am new to unsupervised learning, I am not certain how to reason about this.

Some specific questions:

- Am I correct in worrying about this in the first place?
- Does running PCA reduce/fix any problems?
- Is there an established 'best practice' for cases like this (I have not been able to find one)?

Comment: Interesting questions. I don't have an answer now, but some suggestions:
- did you try using standard scaling instead of min-max scaling? Have you heard about Generalized Low Rank Models? In the 'PCA on a DataFrame' paper authors seem to be addressing something similar to your question

Comment: We haven't tried standard scaling yet, but it's one of the options we considered. However, I figured this problem must be fairly general and hoped there would be one, or a few, standard approach to tackling it.

Answer (score 1):

PCA includes a rotation and a scaling component. You may want to use only one. Or neither, actually.

The better approach is to use a **metric for mixed data** such as Gower's distance.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this. If I understand correctly, what Gower's distance does has the same issues I mention in my question, i.e. the contributions to Gower distance for numerical features are scaled to the unit interval while the contributions from categorical features are always at the extremes of the unit interval.

Comment: Gower scales each feature to have an influence of 1, liked min-max-scaling. PCA reduces the effect of correlated features, for example, and is more related to standardization than min-max-scaling. Which even increases the effect of variables way beyond the unit interval. Try it on a single variable with 1x the value 1 and 99x the value zero. Sure that is what you want?

Comment: But what I worry about is: Consider a dataset where (scaled) house size is uniform over [0,1]. A contribution of ~1 from any pair of houses is rare, because 0 and 1 are at the very extremes.
If the houses are 50/50 regarding garages, approximately every other pair will give a contribution of 1 - the same as the 'extreme' contributions from the sizes.
Is it correct that Gower distance does not change this?

Comment: To my understanding it scales each attribute to 0:1 effectively, yes. But again, PCA and standardization on binary variables can produce much *worse* distortion.